# How to generate 3D mesh from a numpy binary mask

Tags: python, numpy, mesh, marching-cubes

I did a 3D segmentation of an organ in a 3D volume of data acquired in CT.
The output of the segmentation is defined as a binary 3D ndarray, where 1 is inside the organ, and 0 is outside the organ.

What is the best tool to extract the surface of this object as a mesh, that I can then export into a mesh format such as .stl?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a 3D NumPy array of voxels to an STL file](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/10205/convert-a-3d-numpy-array-of-voxels-to-an-stl-file)

Comment: Great, thanks! If you post it as an answer I'll check it as a valid answer

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) out

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that is a best variant, but there is easy way to do it if use [MeshLib](https://github.com/MeshInspector/MeshLib).

To install it on Windows use `py -3.10 -m pip install --upgrade meshlib`

Script to do this will look like:

```py
import meshlib.mrmeshpy as mr
import meshlib.mrmeshnumpy as mrn

#convert 3D array to SimpleVolume data
simpleVolume = mrn.simpleVolumeFrom3Darray(inputData)

#convert SimpleVolume to FloatGrid data
floatGrid = mr.simpleVolumeToDenseGrid(simpleVolume )

#make mesh by iso-value = 0.5 and voxel size = (0.1, 0.1, 0.1)
mesh = mr.gridToMesh(floatGrid , mr.Vector3f(0.1, 0.1, 0.1), 0.5)

#save mesh
mr.saveMesh(mesh, "mesh.stl" )
```

I hope this helps you.